# installing a function from GitHub on offline windows pc

Tags: r

[image][image][image]
I am installing a function from GitHub - ddsjoberg/bstfun: Miscellaneous collection of functions  on offline windows pc using following command. But I get an error of non-zero

install.packages("C:\bstfun-master\bstfun-master", repos = NULL, type="source")

Comment: Try using `remotes::install_git(....)`

Comment: R on Windows requires double-backslashes for directories: `"C:\\bstfun-master\\bstfun-master"`. Or if you don't like the look, R on Windows happily accepts single forward-slashes too, such as `"C:/bstfun-master/bstfun-master"`.

Comment: its says unknow package from Git

Comment: r2@revans, thanks for response.  same error again with different prob. see question for screetshot of the error.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for all your help. just wondering his error could be due to r version?
Which version of r this bstfun-function is compatible? In my offline windows pc I have 4.0.5 version.